# multiple animations (timeline) in react-spring

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have a component with 2 Boxes and a shadow:

First Box is outside the view: topBox
Second Box is inside the view at the bottom: middleBox
Third is the shadow of the Box on the bottom (a png): Shadow

If i start the animation (or if the component loads) i want to have the following animation:

**Step 1**

- middleBox move up 50px
- shadow grows (from scale(0.8) to scale(1))

**Step 2**

- topBox moves down 50px into the view

**Step 3**

(this animation should look like the two boxes smash into each other, like if if they would crash. like two balls hitting each other and go back to origin.)

- middleBox moves up 20px and back down 20px
- topBox moves down 20px and back up 20px
- Shadow scales 1.1 and back to 1

**Step 4**

- topBox moves back outside the view

So i created useSprings for all steps and i tried to update state when the first animation finished based on this update the other animation. i also tried with useChain to have the animations together. But nothing seems to work.

so i would have state

```
const [isAnimationMove, setAnimationMove] = useState(true)
const [isAnimationHit, setIsAnimationHit] = useState(false)
```

and then change the state after the second animation finishes to trigger the new animations

```
const topBoxMoveDown = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate(-20%, 100%)' },  
    transform: 'translate(-10%, 60%)',
    onRest: () => {
        setAnimationMove(false);
        setIsAnimationHit(true);
    }
```

and render the different animation on the element

```
 <BoxFromTop 
     animationStyle={
        isAnimationMove ? topBoxMoveDown :
        isAnimationHit ? topBoxHit : null } />
```

which is

```
const topBoxHit = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'translate(-10%, 60%) rotate(0)' },
    transform: 'translate(-10%, 55%) rotate(10deg)', 
    reset: true,
});
```

However it works kind of as long as i would not use transform again in the topHitBox but i think my question is more about the concept in general:

How do i animate different states and have control over what starts when and what follows what. I mean i just be a simple animation with multiple steps but i can not get my head around how this works with react-spring. Am i using the wrong library? is there a better one to use for this? or did i just use the wrong approach?